# No data is being sent in the final post

Tags: php, opayo

I have had a successful response from SagePay with a registered transaction.

I have filled in all card details, and i know the data is reaching my notificationurl.

but then it stops.  Zero response, and nothing is sent.

To simplify things ive stripped out the code and used hard-coded vars to see if anybody can assist.

```
ob_clean();
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['Status'])){
    if(isset($_POST['Status']) && $_POST['Status'] == 'OK'){
        $data['Status'] = 'OK';
        $data['RedirectURL'] = 'https://www.metano.com/payments/success';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"Status=OK\nRedirectURL=https://www.metano/payments/success");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: basic debugging: `if ($output === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }`

Answer (score 0):

Data passed to cURL as a string should be URLencoded. See the page for [curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and search for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

From php5 upwards, usage of [http_build_query](https://php.net/http_build_query) is recommended: